# trying to centre these logos in html but when on screens less than 500 width i.e mobile

Tags: html, jquery, css, visual-studio

Hi everyone please could you help me with this issue?

im trying to get these (image below) to sit side by side when on smaller screen, i am really trying my hardest but still getting stuck at this anyone can help please and thank you.

its fine on full screen but I cant get it to work

[image]

Code

```
     <div class="container z-depth-1 mx-auto my-5">

    <!-- Section -->
    <section id="view" class="py-5">
  
      <h1 class="font-weight-bold text-center indigo-text mb-5">PROUD TO HAVE COLLABORATED WITH</h1>
  
      <!-- Grid row -->
      <div class="row">
  
        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3  offset-lg-2">
  
          <div class="view">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/Ashurst.png" alt="Sample image">
          </div>
          
          <div class="view">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/Blockchain-HELIX.png" alt="Sample image">
          </div>
          <div class="view">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/S and May.png" alt="Sample image">
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->
  
        <!-- Grid column -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  
          <div class="view">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/Eagle-Labs.png" alt="Sample image">
          </div>
         
          <div class="view">
            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/Strand.png" alt="Sample image">
          </div>
  
          
  
        </div>
        <!-- Grid column -->

   <!-- Grid column -->
   <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">
  
    <div class="view">
      <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/Curtis-Mallet-.png" alt="Sample image">
    </div>

    <div class="view">
      <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/Matrix.png" alt="Sample image">
    </div>

       <div class="view">
      <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/25 bedford.png" alt="Sample image">
    </div>

    

  </div>

  
  <!-- Grid column -->
      </div>
      
      <!-- Grid row -->
  
    </section>
    <!-- Section -->
  
  </div>


CSS

@media (min-width: 576px){
  .container { max-width: 540px;

  }

  #view{

    
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .container { max-width: 720px;

  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px){
  .container { max-width: 960px;

  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px){
  .container { max-width: 1140px;

  }
}
  
  

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #showcase {
    min-height: 500px; }
    #showcase h1 {
      font-size: 4rem; }

  .mb-resp {
    margin-bottom: 1rem; } }
    .brands {
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 90px;
      padding-bottom: 90px
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use display flex on your logo's container:

```css
.logos-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't demonstrate with your code as you haven't provided a [Minimum Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You also haven't attached your Bootstrap dependency or used dummy-images. Not to worry though, this example I made should do:

```css
.logos-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-wrapper {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Logos:</h1>
<div class="logos-container">
  <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"></div>
  <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"></div>
  <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"></div>
  <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have used your answer, how do I now get them to sit one above one below when the screen goes small there is a total of 10 but i want them to be bigger.

Comment: There are three things you can do: 1. Turn on flex-wrap (although I’m not entirely sure they will become bigger), 2. Change the flex-direction using a @media query, 3. Make this same layout, except using CSS grid - Then utilize the [auto-fill or auto-fit](https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/) property.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, on screens bigger than mobile you want to have 3 images on each row, and on smaller screen sizes, you would like only 1.

If this is the case, my suggestion is to get rid of all of those `<div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3">` and add all images on the same level like this

```
<div class="container z-depth-1 mx-auto my-5">
  <section id="view" class="py-5">
    <h1 class="font-weight-bold text-center indigo-text mb-5">PROUD TO HAVE COLLABORATED WITH</h1>
    <div class="collaborators">
      <div class="view">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/Ashurst.png" alt="Sample image">
      </div>
      <div class="view">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/Blockchain-HELIX.png" alt="Sample image">
      </div>
      <div class="view">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/S and May.png" alt="Sample image">
      </div>
      <div class="view">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/Eagle-Labs.png" alt="Sample image">
      </div>
      <div class="view">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/Strand.png" alt="Sample image">
      </div>
      <div class="view">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/Curtis-Mallet-.png" alt="Sample image">
      </div>
      <div class="view">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/Matrix.png" alt="Sample image">
      </div>
      <div class="view">
        <img class="img-fluid mx-auto" src="/25 bedford.png" alt="Sample image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Now you can leverage what display flex can do for you, with a much simpler structure. You can use just a few lines of CSS, to display all your images on columns like so:

```
.collaborators {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.collaborators .view {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .collaborators .view {
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1 1 30%;
  }
}
```

But, to be honest, if it is not a strict requirement to have exactly 3 logos on a row, I would let `display: flex` do its job, without constraining the maximum size of each column.

In order to let `display: flex` do what it does best you can REMOVE these two CSS rules:

```
.collaborators .view {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .collaborators .view {
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1 1 30%;
  }
}
```

And maybe, add some left/right margins on the `.view` class, or use `justify-content` if you like.